# Find out whether AVPlayer is loading or playing mp3 from internet

Tags: ios, avplayer

I would like to use AVPlayer to stream a .mp3 from internet

```
[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

It all works apart from the fact that I am unable to tell whether player is Loading (buffering) or playing ?
I have tried to use KVO on many properties, but none seem to provide me with a simple way of determining whether the AVPlayer is currently actually playing audio or whether it is loading data. It is driving me nuts.

Thank you for your suggestions in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect when buffering is done and playback has started by creating a periodic time observation (using `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:`) to detect when the play time has started to move. For example:

```
AVPlayer *player;

// allocate AVPlayer and start playing

__weak PlayerController *blockSelf = self;
id observerToken = [player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, NSEC_PER_SEC)
                                                              queue:nil
                                                         usingBlock:^ (CMTime time)
                    {
                        if (CMTimeGetSeconds(time) > 0.0)
                        {
                            // done buffering, should be playing now

                            [player removeTimeObserver:[blockSelf playerTimeObserverToken]];
                            [blockSelf setPlayerTimeObserverToken:observerToken:nil];
                        }
                    }];

[self setPlayerTimeObserverToken:observerToken]; // Keep a reference to the token for later use in block.
```

Comment: What is playerTimeObserverToken method?

Comment: @BrandonA It's just a property on self to track the observer token for use when the block gets called. I've updated the example to clarify.